# Flutter: error on build, json_serializable stops working after install realm

Tags: mongodb, flutter, dart, realm, json-serializable

I'm working in a flutter project and after install realm dependency I started getting this error with json_serializable:

[SEVERE] json_serializable...
Found more than one matching converter for `dynamic`.

Do you have something similar?

Thank you!

I dont know what to do :(

Comment: Sounds like a namespace collision with the word 'dynamic'. So if you're using dynamic in your code define it so the compiler knows which one you're referring to, for example, RealmSwift.dynamic. You may also be using older versions of either, or both, libraries. You'll need to do some troubleshooting to determine where the error occurs and if it's within the library itself, file a report on git as there's very little we can do here on SO to help with that.